# Не могу получить JSON строку с помощью Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Здравствуйте, учусь использовать `Retrofit`. Использую AIDE, либы в джарниках. Надо получить ответ от сервера без передачи параметров оному.

> Ссылка: http://chat.pareto-marketing.ru/getform.php

Создал класс

```
public class App63 extends Application
{
private static Api63 api63;
private Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://www.chat.pareto-marketing.ru/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    api63 = retrofit.create(Api63.class);
}

public static Api63 getApi() {
    return api63;
}
}
```

Интерфейс

```
public interface Api63
{
@GET("getform")
Call<ResponseBody> getData();
}
```

Кусок кода активности

```
Call<ResponseBody> list = App63.getApi().getData();

    list.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> p1, Response<ResponseBody> p2)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.d("$", p2.body().string());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {}
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> p1, Throwable p2)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }
        });
}
}
```

Разрешение в манифесте есть. Android 6.0.1

Получаю, его величество, NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference
```

Либы последних версий, обьединил все в один jar. `body.code()` возвращает `404`, `body.message()` возвращает `Not Found`.

Comment: Ну так по ссылке `http://www.chat.pareto-marketing.ru/getform/` у вас json и не отдается

Comment: Ахахахаха, емае, спасибо, вот я идиот))

Comment: Ой да ну ладно, бывает :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface Api63
{
    @GET("getform.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> getData();
}
```

Добавьте `.php`

Comment: Спасибо! Такая глупость, просто в примерах нигде не было `.php`

Comment: @Flippy кстати, раз за retrofit взялись, рекомендую попробовать его в связке с RxJava - вообще бомба

Comment: Попробую, спасибо за идею :)